# Best way to loop over an array of objects and display in HTML/DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

I'm just learning how to use the DOM properly and I'm struggling with how to get my javascript to interact with html. I have an array of objects with info about cats (just to help me learn) that I want to display using HTML, and I'm wondering what is best practice.

- Should I put my data and js in a separate file to my html, or just write it in script tags in the html doc?
- Is there a way I can use template literals in my html to do javascript that way, or does everything have to be a method like getelementbyid ?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome.  Please read [ask], particularly showing _what you've tried_, what research you've done, (as well as limiting to _one question_, you are asking at least two) - and include the latest version of your code, so we have something to work with.  Otherwise, you're asking people here to do _all_ of the work for you, which isn't the spirit of the site :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options you have.

1. You can use jquery templates to bind the data to HTML. The data would be in javascript and you can have placeholders to display that data.
2. You can use Jquery to manipulate your DOM and place data inside HTML elements.
3. You can use some of the javascript frameworks like KnockoutJs to bind data from javascript data to HTML dynamically

The choice really depends on your use case. If you just have to display a read-only information, jquery templates should be fine. Using Jquery is probably easiest to start with, but messy and unmaintainable in the long run. If you have to implement a lot of dynamic data-driven behaviour, then use javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create html div with cats-info id:

```
<div id="cats-info"></div>
```

then in your js file you could find this tag by id

```
const catsInfo = document.getElementById('cats-info');
```

then you could create cat list:

```
const catsData = [
    {name: 'puffy', color: 'black'},
    {name: 'flipper', color: 'white'}
];

function createCatList(cats) {
    return `
       <ul>
           cats.map(cat => convertToCatItem(cat))
       </ul>
`;
}

function convertToCatItem(cat) {
 return `<li>${cat.name} - ${cat.color}</li>`;
}
```

and put your list into you `catsInfo` block;

```
catsInfo.innerHTML = createCatList(catsData);
```

Be free to ask

Comment: hmmm.. I dont think so.. its just printing that string `cats.map(cat => convertToCatItem(cat))`